# grunt not running Qunit tests correctly

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, travis-ci, grunt-contrib-qunit

**Situation** : I am currently using QUnit to test a project in TypeScript/Javascript and everything works fine when I'm running them in a browser.

**Problem** : I'm trying to use grunt to run the QUnit tests in a headless mode (I need it for continuous integration testing) and the tests don't run properly.

**Configuration**
Here's how I have things currently set up :

```
Gruntfile.js
package.json
src/
  - Ts source files
test/
  - config.js
  - Test.ts
  - Test.js
  - test.html
```

*Gruntfile.js*

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8000,
                    base: '.'
                }
            }
        },

        qunit: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    urls: [
                        'http://localhost:8000/test/test.html'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    grunt.registerTask('test', ['connect', 'qunit']);

};
```

*package.json*

```
{
  // Name, version, description, repo and author fields...
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.5.2"
  }
}
```

And then I have a *.travis.yml* file to run all of this. I don't know if it's really important because the tests don't run either in travis or in my local environment, but here is it anyways :

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "0.11"
 - "0.10"
before_install:
 - "npm install grunt --save-dev"
 - "npm install -g grunt-cli"
install:
 - "npm install"
 - "npm install -g typescript"
script:
 - "tsc --module amd --target ES5 ./src/*.ts"
 - "grunt test --verbose --force"
```

And here's the part that errors in the travis build : http://puu.sh/eKpWj/35614680e1.png

(I currently have ~20 assertions that pass when I'm running them in a browser. Also, the typescript compilation runs ok.)

Edit : And as someone asked fot it, here's the content of the Test.html file : http://pastebin.com/LN3igmjc

Edit 2 : Here's also the content of *config.js* :

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "../src/"
};
```

Comment: It looks you might be using requirejs, is that correct?

Comment: In any case, can you show us your qunit HTML file?

Comment: Yes, I am using requirejs.

Comment: Hmm, require uses Ajax to get dependencies, and if you're not running a web server those calls might fail. Have you tried setting up a simple [connect server](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) and using `localhost`?

Comment: Haven't tried it, I'll do it as soon as I can. However, ain't that strange that it runs ok in a browser ? Also you asked for the content of the HTML file, here it is -> http://pastebin.com/LN3igmjc

Comment: Some browsers are ok with non-full-http Ajax calls and some aren't. Phantom is weird like that.

Comment: Can you show the contents of that `config.js` file as well?

Comment: I edited the question with the content of `config.js`

Comment: @jakerella Thanks for your suggestion, I did as you said, and ran a connect server using the link you provided. I have also edited my question that now reflects all the results I'm getting by trying the tests through `localhost` (look at the travis output) : it looks like there is still something wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I managed to make it work.
I changed two things :

1. I wasn't compiling the tests, as `tsc --module amd --target ES5 ./src/*.ts` compiled the files in the `src` folder, and the test files were in the `test` folder. *I'm bashing myself for this one...*
   So I simply added `tsc --module amd --target ES5 ./test/*.ts` in the `.travis.yml` file
2. The biggest problem was that the QUnit tests were trying to start before the work of require.js. The solution I used was to tell QUnit to not start tests automatically by using `QUnit.config.autostart = false;` and make them start when I want with `QUnit.start();` I placed this start() at the end of my `Test.js` file so that the tests start only when QUnit is done loading.